# Nodejs Express basicAuth custom login page

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication

I am currently using node.js express to create a webserver.  I am using the following for authentication:

```
app.use(express.basicAuth(function(user, pass) {
  return user === XXX && pass === YYY;
}));
```

but when the user is not logged in it simply opens a basic popup for the users credentials.  How can I modify this to allow me to create custom loginpage the user gets routed to and then sends the login credentials back?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could probably try this:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    res.send({
        //the user and pw
    })
}, express.basicAuth(function(user, pass) {
    return user === "XXX" && pass === "YYY";
}));
```

So that whenever you post from a certain form in the site, it will lead to the callback basicAuth that is used to authenticate against the user. Anycase, you should be using express 4.0 instead of express 3.0 now as 3.0 is deprecated.